# remove class to selected variants with JS

Tags: javascript, shopify

Hi there im making some adjustments to my product page, where i want to show/hide selected variants.

```
filterMedia() {
const variantSwatches = document.querySelectorAll("[data-variant-color]");
for (const variant of variantSwatches) {
  variant.style.display = "none";
}

var selected_variant = this.currentVariant.featured_media.alt;
var selected_attribute =
  '[data-variant-color="' + selected_variant + '"]';

if (selected_variant == selected_variant) {
  console.log(selected_attribute);
}
```

I created this part of code with vanilla JS, first of all i add style="none" to all div with data-variant-color, then i get selected variant:

```
console.log(selected_attribute);
```

[image]

[image]

Just need to remove style="none" of all variants doesn't be == to selected variant.

I'm a little bit confused, if anyone can help me with this :)

**EDIT V2**

```
    updateVariantImage() {
const dataVariants = document.querySelectorAll("[data-variant-color]");
dataVariants.forEach((dataVariant) => {
  dataVariant.style.display = "none";
});

var selected_variant = this.currentVariant.featured_media.alt;
var selected_attribute = '[data-variant-color="' + selected_variant + '"]';

if (selected_variant == selected_variant) {
const getVariants = document.querySelector(selected_attribute);
console.log(getVariants);
}
```

}
[image]

Comment: Did you mean `style="display:none;"` ?

Comment: @MaxPattern exacly, if you see in second image all divs with data-variant-color get style=“none”, i need to remove all unselected variants, thanks :)

Comment: I don't see it in your code, but you keep referencing `style="none"`. "none" by itself is not a valid style. Set `style.display="";` to reset to the default display.

Comment: @mykaf i added style.display="none" at first of all elements with data-variant-color, and then get on console option selected with "console.log(selected_attribute);", at the moment is what i have, now i want to add to selected option style.display="" to reset display only on that variant

Comment: Okay, I don't understand why you are unable to do so.

Comment: edited original post with new code added, but i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display') @mykaf

Comment: you need to query select the selected variant like it `document.querySelector('selected_attribute')` and then use like this one `document.querySelector('selected_attribute').style.display = 'block`

Comment: @Onkar thanks for your help, anyway i edited original post with code i have at the moment, but i get property = null

Comment: opps, `document.querySelector('selected_attribute')` this should be like `document.querySelector(selected_attribute)`

Comment: @Onkar thanks :) it solve that issue, at the moment we managed to get only first div with data-variant-color (left an image on original post, and edited code with last version we have at the moment, so how can i select every div with black or steel in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector` it returns the 1st instance.
so you need to loop on the element that meets the condtions like this

```
const getVariants = document.querySelectorAll(selected_attribute);
getVariants.forEach(function(ele){
  ele.stle.display = 'block';
});
```

You can read more about [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) here